# Upsert an array of items with MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I've got an array of objects I'd like to insert into a MongoDB collection, however I'd like to check if each item already exists in the collection first. If it doesn't exist then insert it, if it does exist then don't insert it.

After some Googling it looks like I'm best using the update method with the upsert property set to true.

This seems to work fine if I pass it a single item, as well as if I iterate over my array and insert the items one at a time, however I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to do this, or if it's the most efficient. Here's what I'm doing at the moment:

```
var data = [{}, {}, ... {}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var item = data[i];

  collection.update(
    {userId: item.id},
    {$setOnInsert: item},
    {upsert: true},
    function(err, result) {

      if (err) {
        // Handle errors here
      }

  });

}
```

Is iterating over my array and inserting them one-by-one the most efficient way to do this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two options here, depending your *exact* needs:

- If you need to **insert or update** use an [upsert query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option). In that case, if the object is already present you will update it -- assuming your document will have some content, this means that you will possibly overwrite the previous value of some fields. As you noticed, using [`$setOnInsert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) will mitigate that issue.
- If you need to **insert or ignore** add an [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) on the related fields and let the insert fail on duplicate key. As you have several documents to insert, you might send them all in an array using an [*unordered* insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#perform-an-unordered-insert) (i.e.: setting the `ordered` option to `false`) so MongoDB will continue to insert the remaining documents in case of error with one of them.

As about performances, with the second option MongoDB will use the index to look up for a possible duplicate. So chances are good this would perform better.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I need. I did start out by trying to insert the whole array, which failed and stopped when it encountered a duplicate, which is why I thought I may need to do it in the way I outlined in the question. I wasn't aware that you could use an unordered insert to continue the insert even if some of the inserts fail. Thanks!

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux Does this remain the best way to achieve this as of Mongo 3.3 ? Looks inefficient. Thanks.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg I take a quick look at 3.4 release notes (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/) and didn't see anything that could invalidate that or did I missed it?

As about this being "inefficient": could you elaborate? FWIW, using an index will allow an early detection of collisions before the data are touched. This will also ensure the insert is atomic, as oposite to read-check-then-write solution, so you won't have hare a concurrent read operation seing dirty data nor race conditions if two concurent access are simultaneously trying to modify the same document.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I am a newcomer to Mongo, and therefore wanted to check if this was the best way. Coming from SQL I used to batch inserts.
Thanks for the thoughtful reply. S